# New Data Series shifted left

Tags: pine-script

I have indicator that alerts on condition. Just alerts.
Using just closes.
Sometimes I know for example that if the next (current) close will be up or down - alert will happen.
So, idea is next:
shift chart left for 1 bar, fill last empty with required value and calculate indicator from this new data series. As if it has been closed (current bar). Just to be ready fast.
I've tried to do it with array (filling it with close data until last, filling last with desired value). But I can't calculate indicator value from array data.
Are any decision exits to convert array to data series or may be dramatically other decision?

`

```
a = array.new_float(50)
for i = 1 to 49
    array. Set(a, i, close[i-1])
array. Set(a, 0, myValue)
```

I've tried to fill array this way. But can't calculate